# How to download an .xlsx file from a url?

Tags: url, google-apps-script, download, xlsx

So basically I receive a report everyday from an advertising platform which is a url, once I click on it starts downloading an excel file on my browser.

I work on Google app script and can't figure out what should I do in order to download the file. Ideally once I can get access to the .xlsx file, I will convert it into .csv with a ...

var csv = theFile.getAs('text/csv')

.. which would then be easy to paste in a gsheet. If anyone as an idea on how to process that would be super helpful.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the actual link so we can advise on how to get the file? Also, it would help if you could share all that you've tried so far - from the code POV.

Comment: Heyy unfortunately I can't share the link because it contains some sensitive data of my client... However I can share some of the code so far (tbf, for now its mainly going to my gmail, apply some label, extract the correct thread and last email to find the url of the report...

Comment: if (subject == reportName && sentFrom == expeditor && date == today.valueOf()) {
      
        var body = email.getBody()
        var startIndex = body.indexOf("Report download URL: ")
        var endIndex = body.indexOf("This download link expires on")
        var substring = body.substring(startIndex, endIndex)
        
        var startIndex2 = substring.indexOf("http")
        var endIndex2 = substring.indexOf('">')
        var url = substring.substring(startIndex2, endIndex2)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file isn't behind any password-protected site:

```
var link = '{{link}}';

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link);
var excelfile = DriveApp.createFile(response);

var driveresource = 
   {
      title: excelfile.getName(),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE.SHEETS
   };

  Drive.Files.insert(driveresource,response);
```

This should download the Excel file and create the google sheet in the main drive folder.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for coming back to me, I've tried this code but I receive this error message:

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for coming back to me, I've tried this code but I receive this error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'SHEETS' of undefined

Also, are the double curly brackets necessary around the url?

Comment: The above code works, I've test it.

The curly brakets are not needed you should exchange {{link}} for your actual https://... link

Comment: @AlexandraMorel-Fonteray, I was able to duplicate the error you received when the file that is being referenced in the link is not actually the Excel file blob.  When you removed the curly brackets from the link, did that resolve your issue or are you still getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked, I actually needed to go into 
Resources > Advanced Google Service > turn on "Drive API"

```
        var finalUrl = url1.toString().replace(/%3A/g,':').replace(/%2F/g,'/').replace(/%3F/g,'?').replace(/%26/g,'&').replace(/%3D/g,'=').replace(/%25/g,'%')

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalUrl);
    var excelfile = DriveApp.createFile(response);

    var driveresource = 
  {
    title: excelfile.getName(),
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };

   Drive.Files.insert(driveresource,response);
```

And here I go! I'm not sure how to find the URL of the file newly created though...

But in anyway thanks to you and @Sourabh Choraria for helping me out here.